# Find the general formula for the sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, recurrence-relations, recursion, pattern-recognition

> 1=1
>
> 2+3+4+=1+8
>
> 5+6+7+8+9=8+27
>
> 10+11+12+13+14+15+16=27+64

Find the formula is suggested by these equations?Prove your answer is correct.

I saw this question on practice exam and the answer is = (2n-1)(n²-n+1) but I only know a few steps and didn't get this answer. Please explain. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Each equation is the sum of the terms from the number after the last perfect square to the next perfect square. The sum of consecutive integers from $a_1$ to $a_m$ is given by $\frac{m}{2}(a_1+a_m)$  where m is the number of terms being added up.

Now if $n$ is the equation number, the first term, $a_1$, is one more than the previous square, $(n-1)^2+1$, and the last term, $a_m$, is the number squared ($n^2$). The number of terms is the odd sequence, so $m=2n-1$. Putting this together we have:

$$\frac{2n-1}{2}\left((n-1)^2+1+n^2\right)$$
$$=\left(2n-1\right)\left(n^2-n+1\right)$$

If we multiply and manipulate this it gives the pattern on the right:

$$2n^3-3n^2+3n-1$$
$$=n^3-3n^2+3n-1+n^3$$
$$=(n-1)^3+n^3$$

Comment: so which is the formula ? =(2n−1)($n^2$−n+1) or this =$(n−1)^3$+$n^3$?

Comment: Well notice that the expressions on the right side of the equations is the previous equation number cubed (n-1)^3 plus the equation number cubed, n^3. I would go for the second one to answer the question, but the first one is an intermediate step to get to this expression.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the formula for arithmetic sequence? $${(a_1+a_n)n\over2}$$

You need to apply it to find the first number: $(1+2n-3)(n-1)\over2$$=(n-1)^2+1$

And you need to apply it again to find the sum: $((n-1)^2+1+(n-1)^2+2n-1)(2n-1)\over2$$=(2n-1)(n^2-n+1)$

Comment: I need to look up the arithmetic sequence formula  first in order to know where 1,2n and 3 come from right?

Comment: No, for that part it comes from the first number of $n$th line is always $(1+3+5+7+...+2n-3)+1$ because the lines before it has lengths $1,3,5,7,..,2n-3$. But to calculate $1+3+5+7+...+2n-3$ you need the arithmetic formula.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote $q$ the index of an equation (starting from $q=1$), and the LHS is

$$(p^2+1)+(p^2+2)+\cdots+q^2,$$ where $p=q-1$. Indeed, the sequence of all LHS terms is continuous and there are $q^2-p^2$ of them, which equals $q+p$ and increases by two every time.

As we have an arithmetic progression, by pairing opposite terms we see that we can replace all of them by the middle one, $\dfrac{(p^2+1)+q^2}2=q^2-q+1=q^2-pq+p^2$.

Then, the sum of the terms equals

$$(q+p)(q^2-pq+p^2)=p^3+q^3.$$

Comment: I see you commented two answers so this one will work better right?

Comment: "work better" ? This is mostly a matter of taste. My other answer is a "proof without words". Establishing it made me reconsider my first answer and bring simpler explanations/formulas, in particular how to get a sum of cubes. Anyway, I don't like the "house" shape it takes.

Answer (score 0):

$$\color{blue}1=1\\
2+\color{blue}3+4=3+3+3\\
5+6+\color{blue}7+8+9=7+7+7+7+7\\
10+11+12+\color{blue}{13}+14+15+16=13+13+13+13+13+13+13\\
17+18+19+20+\color{blue}{21}+22+23+24+25=21+21+21+21+21+21+21+21+21$$

$$\begin{align}
1\cdot1&=(1+0)(1^2-0)=(1+0)(1^2-1\cdot0+0^2)=1^3+0^3\\
3\cdot3&=(2+1)(2^2-1)=(2+1)(2^2-2\cdot1+1^2)=2^3+1^3\\
5\cdot7&=(3+2)(3^2-2)=(3+2)(3^2-3\cdot2+2^2)=3^3+2^3\\
7\cdot13&=(4+3)(4^2-3)=(4+3)(4^2-4\cdot3+3^2)=4^3+3^3\\
9\cdot21&=(5+4)(5^2-4)=(5+4)(5^2-5\cdot4+4^2)=5^3+4^3\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Using $-a=-(a+1)a+a^2$ and $(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=a^3+b^3$.